# Encontar palabra en frase

Tags: r, regex

Tengo el siguiente df:

```
datos<-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), col2=c("WS2 lechuga","Q1","E1 pata1ta","E2 limon2","E1 tom2ate","G1 1manza1na","G2 pera","E2"),stringsAsFactors=F )
```

```
col1         col2
1    1  WS2 lechuga
2    2           Q1
3    3   E1 pata1ta
4    4    E2 limon2
5    5   E1 tom2ate
6    6 G1 1manza1na
7    7      G2 pera
8    8           E2
```

Quiero detectar las letras E1,E2,G1,G2 y que me lo pongan en otra columna, el resto se borra.

```
datos[grepl("E1", datos$col2), "Nuevo"]="E1"
datos[grepl("E2", datos$col2), "Nuevo"]="E2"
datos[grepl("G1", datos$col2), "Nuevo"]="G1"
datos[grepl("G2", datos$col2), "Nuevo"]="G2"
```

```
  col1         col2 Nuevo
1    1  WS2 lechuga  <NA>
2    2           Q1  <NA>
3    3   E1 pata1ta    E1
4    4    E2 limon2    E2
5    5   E1 tom2ate    E1
6    6 G1 1manza1na    G1
7    7      G2 pera    G2
8    8           E2    E2
```

Quiero tener el mismo resultado pero sin tener que repetirlo muchas veces.
He intentado algo como esto:

```
datos$col3<- gsub("(\\E\\d{1}).*|(\\G\\d{1}).*", "\\1\\2", datos$col2)
```

pero no me pone NA en el resto de las palabras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `grepl()` para ver si encuentaras el partrón y `gsub()` para capturarlo:

```
patron <- "(E\\d{1}).*|(G\\d{1}).*"
datos$col3 <- ifelse(grepl(patron, datos$col2), 
                     gsub("(E\\d{1}).*|(G\\d{1}).*", "\\1\\2", datos$col2), 
                     NA)
datos  

  col1         col2 col3
1    1  WS2 lechuga <NA>
2    2           Q1 <NA>
3    3   E1 pata1ta   E1
4    4    E2 limon2   E2
5    5   E1 tom2ate   E1
6    6 G1 1manza1na   G1
7    7      G2 pera   G2
8    8           E2   E2
```